# Visual C# and SQL Server not working correctly together // file is already in use

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, entity-framework-4

In the last few days I was finally studying how to connect my C# application (I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Express) to my SQL Server 2008 R2 database by using Entity Framework and I am totally stuck.

When I want to ADD a new DataSource in VS I just find the path of my db file and when I finally find it and try to select it, it throws me an error that shows

> This File is already in use. Enter new name or close that file, which is used by another application

That sounds to me like nonsense because I wasn't using my database file for two days. So after a bit of googling I finally found a solution and I entered to the SQL Server Configuration Manager and restarted my only SQL Server.

Then my DataSource connection finally **works** and I was thinking that now I'm unbeatable and I'll write my code till end of days but after a few minutes I got another problem :O (the reason I'm writing here).

When I use **any** part of SQL Server in my VS application then my SQL Server stops working. I can't browse the database there, I can't change anything, I can't use query, just nothing. It just tells me that this database is already in use.

It's the same when I do it in the opposite way.

I restart SQL Server via SQL Server Configuration Manager (to be able to use SQL Server again) and then I, for example, use my DB query task `SELECT * FROM nameDatabase`.

Then I tried to debug my C# application where I have a combobox into which SQL Server has to fill some names and I get the error that SQL Server is not accessible. (I can't tell you the exact error right now but after googling I found that it means that SQL Server is not accessible).

If anyone wants to see that code then it is:

```
using (var entities = new PropertyDatabaseEntities())
{
    var userNames = entities.Login
                .Select(login => login.Username)
                .ToArray();

    comboboxLogin.Items.Clear();
    comboboxLogin.Items.AddRange(userNames);
}
```

But when I restart SQL Server and turn this debug before I use anything from SQL Server it works.

Some people were telling me I am not closing my connections but that can't be true because even when I use SQL Server first then I still can't use connection between VS and SQL Server.

I am really stuck.

*Connection String

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings><add name="Final.Properties.Settings.PropertyDatabaseConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=&quot;C:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\PropertyDatabase.mdf&quot;;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /><add name="LoginEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DataAccess.LoginModel.csdl|res://*/DataAccess.LoginModel.ssdl|res://*/DataAccess.LoginModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=&quot;C:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\Login.mdf&quot;;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /><add name="PropertyEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DataAccess.PropertyModel.csdl|res://*/DataAccess.PropertyModel.ssdl|res://*/DataAccess.PropertyModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=&quot;C:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\Property.mdf&quot;;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /><add name="PropertyDatabaseEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DataAccess.PropertyDatabaseModel.csdl|res://*/DataAccess.PropertyDatabaseModel.ssdl|res://*/DataAccess.PropertyDatabaseModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=&quot;C:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\PropertyDatabase.mdf&quot;;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: The way you've coded the USING statement means the connection will be managed correctly and closed.

Comment: Can you post your connection string?

Comment: _"This File is already in use. Enter new name or close that file, wich is used by another application."_ is not a known error. What is the exact error and around what lines does that happen?

Comment: `i was thinking that now im unbeatable and ill write my codes till end of days but after few minutes i got another problem` - oh lord. `I cant tell you the exact error right now but after googling i found that it means that sql is not accessible` - please show us the error message with Stack Trace - the error should be in your browsing history.

Comment: "This File is already in use. Enter new name or close that file, wich is used by another application." this message i got when im trying to adding DB with DataSource without restarting SQL server.

Comment: You probably have a fundamentally wrong understanding of how to use SQL Server. Main point is: it's a **server** - e.g. you shouldn't be messing around with files (browsing to a file and opening it). You create your database **on the server** (using SQL Server Mgmt Studio Express), and then you connect to that database by specifying it's logical name - **no file name** involved! Basically, your application just talks to the server process of SQL Server - you're not dealing with files yourself - let that by handled by SQL Server!

Comment: Yes Marc_s, I am not doing anything with the files by myself. I was just trying to connect the db file to studio by "Data Source". Thats all I ever done with any db files by myself.

Comment: Jeremy Thompson: "The unerlying provider failed to Open." is error what i get on trying to fill combobox. I am sorry that i cant send you Stack Trace but I dont ahve now my notebook with me. I will post it here in few hour. btw About that unbeatable? That have to be joke. It really wasnt mean seriously. :)

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to attach the Database files instrad of creating a proper TDS connection to the server. I helped with a similiar problem on a JDBC type connection about a year ago. Is it possible to post the connection string for us. I suspect you are trying to attach the database file which is NOT the recommended way of opening a connection.

Comment: Thanks for response and I save that connection string on the end of my post.

Answer (score 2):

AttachDBFilename is unique to SQL Express.  Database is simply the name of the database to use, it has no additional connotation.  For any production server, you would most likely not be using AttachDBFilename.  It is strictly useful for development and experimentation in single-user mode.

You had to change data source=.\SQLEXPRESS on the production server and remove attachdbfilename section from your connection string

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the logical name instead of the filename/path in your connection string.  I **THINK** 'AttachDbFileName=' feature is for SQL Server EXPRESS edition. But it isn't suggested for production at least, and it is just not the recommended way to establish a connection.

**instead of FILE NAME and PATH**

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=&quot;C:\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\PropertyDatabase.mdf&quot
```

**TRY LOGICAL NAME**

server=localhost\SQLEXPR5;database=yourdatabase; user id = sa;password=;

Take a look at [www.connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/)